# $S_1\times S_2$ is a semi-algebra on $\Omega_1\times\Omega_2$

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $S_i, i=1,2$ be semi-algebras of subsets of $\Omega_i,i=1,2$ respectively. Prove that $S_1\times S_2$ is a semi-algebra on $\Omega_1\times\Omega_2$.

Going by the definition, I want to prove

1. $(\Omega_1,\Omega_2)\in S_1\times S_2$
2. If $(A_1,A_2)\in S_1\times S_2$ such that $A_1\in S_1, A_2\in S_2$ then, $(A_1,A_2)^c\in S_1\times S_2$
3. For any $n$ and $(A_1,B_1),(A_2,B_2),...(A_n,B_n)\in S_1\times S_2$ such that $A_i\in S_1,B_i\in S_2\forall i$ then, $\cup_{i=1}^n(A_i,B_i)\in S_1\times S_2$

To prove 2 and 3 I used $(A_1,A_2)^c=(A_1^c,A_2^c)$ and $\cup_{i=1}^n(A_i,B_i)=(\cup A_i,\cup B_i)$. Is this method okay?

Comment: You are actually trying to prove that this is an algebra. You may want to review the definition of a semi-algebra https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiring#Semiring_of_sets .

Comment: @coudy oh right my bad! thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a very good point in asking this question. However, it should begin before checking the three defining properties of a semi-algebra, namely with the somewhat hidden property of a semialgebra to be a subset of the power set.

I think that this is the origin of your confusion, and for good reason, since the usual definition of a product set as the set of pairs,
$$
S_{1}\times S_{2} = \{ (A_{1},A_{2}) \mid A_{1} \in S_{1},\, A_{2} \in S_{2} \} 
\color{red}{\not\subseteq} \mathcal{P}(\Omega_{1} \times \Omega_{2})
$$
is not even a subset of the corresponding power set!

The way this is meant (slightly abusing/overloading notation) is as the set of products
$$
S_{1}\times S_{2} = \{ A_{1} \times A_{2} \mid A_{1} \in S_{1},\, A_{2} \in S_{2} \} 
\color{green}{\subseteq} \mathcal{P}(\Omega_{1} \times \Omega_{2}).
$$
Does this help?

Comment: oh so not the "usual" cartesian product. it does make more sense now because $A_1,A_2$ are themselves sets. But, I'm still a little confused on how to prove the two properties. Is this true? $(A_1\times A_2)\cap(B_1\times B_2)=(A_1\cap B_1)\times(A_2\cap B_2)$ seems to be true with a "recatngle" visualization

Comment: @zaira Yes! $(x_1,x_2) \in (A_1\times A_2)\cap (B_1\times B_2)$ iff [$(x_1,x_2) \in (A_1\times A_2)$ and $(x_1,x_2) \in (B_1\times B_2)$] iff [$x_1\in A_1$ and $x_2 \in A_2$ and $x_1\in B_1$ and $x_2 \in B_2$] iff [$x_1\in A_1\cap B_1$ and $x_2 \in A_2\cap B_2$] iff $(x_1,x_2) \in (A_1 \cap B_1)\times (A_2\cap B_2)$. Harder to write down than to explain, but I hope you get my meaning.. It's only using definitions.